# How to paste a line from the copy buffer to the end of each line?

Tags: vim, paste

I have a file whose content looks like this (over a few hundred lines):

```
+incdir+/a/b/c/

file_interface.c
file_fifo.c
file_thing.c
```

I need to transform the file so that it looks like this:

```
file_interface.c +incdir+/a/b/c/
file_fifo.c +incdir+/a/b/c/
file_thing.c +incdir+/a/b/c/
```

I know that I can copy the first line to the copy buffer then paste it to any character using the Control-V then P, but it seems that this command does not work with the paste location is specifically in the end of each line. How could I do that instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can delete the entire line into a named buffer and use a normal command to append the buffer to each line

```
"aD
:%norm $"ap
```

or using the default buffer <sub>cudo's to D. Ben Knoble</sub>

```
D
:%norm! $p
```

Comment: In fact, `"*` is not the default buffer—you probably meant `:%norm! $p`

Comment: This one won for the simplicity. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

My attempt

On the first line:

```
gg0yg_ ................. this will copy the first line without carriage return
```

Now let's run a global command:

```
:%g/^file_/exec "normal! A \<c-r>0"
```

How it works:

```
:%g/^file_/exec ................. over the whole file
" ............................... using double quotes we use keystroke notation
normal! ......................... normal command
A ............................... start insert at the end of line and add one space
\<c-r>0 ......................... inserts the copy register

:1,2d ........................... delete the first two lines
```

We can even create a function with all on it:

```
fun! CopyToEnd()
    :normal gg0"+yg_
    :1,2d
    :g/file_/exe "normal! A \<c-r>+"
endfun
nnoremap <F5> :call CopyToEnd()<cr>
```

Then you can copy this funtion to your clipboard and run:

```
:@+
```

Now just press `<F5>`

Comment: You don't need `:%g`; simply `:g` is enough. Also, `gg0yg_` could be changed to `ggy$`

Comment: Using g_ we avoid possibly copying carriage return

Comment: Sure, but `y$` does not copy `<cr>` either. The difference between `g_` and `$` is that `$` will include the trailing spaces if any. However, that does not seem to be a case for the OP. (Also note that `gg0` could forcefully include the leading spaces if any).

Answer (score 1):

Delete the first line:

```
:1delete
```

Remove the end-of-line:

```
:let @" = substitute(@", '\n', '', '')
```

Paste and join:

```
:global/^file/put | join
```